# In android how to store EditText values in ArrayList

Tags: android

I am manually creating the `EditText` in `for` loop. How can i store all the values in `ArrayList` in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arryList = new ArrayList<String>();  
 arryList.add(editText.getText().toString());
```

this should help..

Comment: then u must ve done something wrong with getting instance of editText.. check to see whether editText holds null.. check in debug mode..

Comment: ArrayList<String> arryList = new ArrayList<String>();  
  arryList.add(f1.getText().toString());  String ftname = f1.getText().toString();